# Need some help in creating a visual representation of device orientation using JS

Tags: javascript, css

Basically, I am wanting to create a visual representation of the device orientation values alpha, beta, and gamma. So far I have managed to display the values in plain text using innerHTML, but I want to create a series of "bars" for each value. I drew a very crude drawing of what I had in mind:[image]

Basically, I want the bars to move in relation to changes in the alpha, beta and gamma values. This is how my code looks now.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <body>
    <p>Alpha: <span id="alpha"></span></p>
    <p>Beta: <span id="beta"></span></p>
    <p>Gamma: <span id="gamma"></span></p>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
      // Listen for device orientation event
      window.ondeviceorientation = function(eventData)
      {
        // Show alpha, beta and gamma values
        document.getElementById('alpha').innerHTML = Math.round(eventData.alpha);
        document.getElementById('beta').innerHTML = Math.round(eventData.beta);
        document.getElementById('gamma').innerHTML = Math.round(eventData.gamma);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I highly doubt I can do this using inner HTML because I think I would need to use CSS styling. This makes me think that the canvas might work, but I have trouble initializing it using the ondeviceorientation. I would appreciate any help in accomplishing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a canvas. You can do this just by altering the width of your spans along with using CSS to set the colors.

Firstly make sure your spans have a CSS property of `display : inline-block` or `display : block`or else changing the width will do nothing. Alternatively you can make them divs instead of spans. Also make sure it has a height property set such as `30px`.

Next you can use css or inline-styles to set the `background-color` property for alpha, beta, and gamma. Then simply change the `Element.style.width` property (in px) based on the device orientation using javascript.

Something you might want to consider deeply is what you want the size of the bars to represent and their precise behavior. That design decision is up to you, so I won't explain in excruciating detail how the following code works, but basically I size them relative to the range of the values. I turn the value of alpha, beta, and gamma respectively into a percentage of their total range and then multiply that by the max width I would like for the bars.

I grabbed the ranges from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation

The general formula is for values in range `[a, b]` and a maximum bar width of `max_w`, and alpha, beta, or gamma value of `value`, the calculated width of the bar is:

`width = max_w * ( ( -a + value ) / (b - a) )`

And don't forget to add "px" to the end.

```js
// Listen for device orientation event
window.ondeviceorientation = function(eventData)
{
  let maxWidth = 200;
  // Show alpha, beta and gamma values
  document.getElementById('alpha').style.width = Math.round(maxWidth * eventData.alpha / 360) + "px";
  
  document.getElementById('beta').style.width = Math.round(maxWidth * (180 + eventData.beta) / 360) + "px";
  document.getElementById('gamma').style.width = Math.round(maxWidth * (90 + eventData.gamma) / 180) + "px";
}
```

```css
p span{
  height : 30px;
  display : inline-block;
}

#alpha{
  background-color : green;
}

#beta { 
  background-color : yellow;
}

#gamma {
  background-color : purple
}
```

```html
<p> Alpha: <span id="alpha"> </span> </p>
<p> Beta: <span id="beta"> </span> </p>
<p> Gamma: <span id="gamma"> </span></p>
```

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to display the numeric value beside the alpha:, and the bar underneath that? I tried putting a seperate span for the bars, but the values displayed overlapping the numeric values

Comment: I am 100% positive there is a way to do what you're describing, but I think I'd need more information to understand what it is you're trying to do. (Consider asking a new question on SO)

Comment: thanks, I was able to figure it out with a bit more looking around. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The previous poster, Khauri McClain, posted a good suggestion for a static representation of your orientation values. If by "move" you mean, however, an animation (and hence refer to canvas), then you can still do it without canvas, but instead using CSS `keyframes`. Here is quick example.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f7f9;
  color: #6c6c6c;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 30em;
  margin: 2em;
}

.label {
  float: left;
  width: 5em;
  height: 2em;
}

.orientation {
  float: right;
  background-color: #e5e9eb;
  height: 2em;
  position: relative;
  width: 24em;
}

.alpha {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: alpha-anim;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  background-color: #ff2d55;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.beta {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: beta-anim;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  background-color: #4cd964;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.gamma {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: gamma-anim;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  background-color: #007aff;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes alpha-anim {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 14em;
  }
}

@keyframes beta-anim {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 3em;
  }
}

@keyframes gamma-anim {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 20em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="label">Alpha:</div>
  <div class="orientation">
    <div class="alpha"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="label">Beta:</div>
  <div class="orientation">
    <div class="beta"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="label">Gamma:</div>
  <div class="orientation">
    <div class="gamma"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```